# Why is Data loading as Nan in Mongodb (PyMongo)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a column in CSV which is empty, but when loaded  into MongoDb (by using Pymonogo), I am getting as "NaN". How can I set it to Blank (Empty string,"") by default. I don't want to run a replace command as every time I don't want to replace "NaN" with "".

Regards,

Smar

Comment: Can't really tell much about why or what to do about it without seeing a sample of the data and the command that loads it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much detail but assuming you are using pandas, you could try something like:

```
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), "")
```

to replace nulls(NaNs) with an empty string.